# Problem accessing Windows registry keys using variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get the values of windows registry keys, and the registry keys are read in from a spreadsheet in two parts (key_part_1 & key_part_2) details are in the code snippet.

I understand why the first line works as its converting the text to a raw string, but I can't wotk out how to do the samewith the variable "key_part_2".

This line works: `key_name = OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IsoBurn\Capabilities\FileAssociations")`

But this line gives an error: `key_name = OpenKey(key_part_1, key_part_2)`

Error Message:

```
File "C:\Users\dugle\Documents\Dougs Python Scripts\Excel.py", line 79, in get_reg_key_value
    key_name = OpenKey(key_part_1, key_part_2)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: The object is not a PyHKEY object
```

The full code is below:

```
def get_reg_key_value(key_part_1, key_part_2):
    # key_part_1 = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
    # key_part_2 = SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IsoBurn\Capabilities\FileAssociations
    # key_name = OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IsoBurn\Capabilities\FileAssociations")
    key_name = OpenKey(key_part_1, key_part_2)
    try:
        count = 0
        while 1:
            k_name, k_value, k_type = winreg.EnumValue(key_name, count)
            ic(k_name, k_value)
            count = count + 1
    except WindowsError:
        pass
```

Comment: What are the actual values of `key_part_1` and `key_part_2`? In the code above, both definitions have been commented out.

Comment: `key_part_2` isn't the problem, `key_part_1` is. If `key_part_1` is *the string* `"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"`, that's not what `OpenKey` expects. It expects one of the [defined constants](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html#hkey-constants); not a string which has the name of one of those constants. You probably need `getattr(winreg, key_part_1)`…?!

Comment: The problem is in the code that calls this function. It needs to use the constant `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` rather than a string.

Comment: @deceze if you post your comment as an answer, I can mark it as such then.